# Gray out divs / page content while page is loading

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

how can I achive something similar to youdemy's way of loading pages ?
as you can see the divs/ the page content is grayed out initially and once the page
loads the content appears.

How can I achieve something similar to this ?

Comment: Use an SVG image? What have you tried so far?

Comment: There would be pleinty of possibilities to achieve this (empty divs with grey background, placeholder image, etc.). Please give it a try, come back with your code and your attempt, then people can help you where you're stuck. But we can't simply develop your whole solution for free.

Comment: While loading udemy, as soon as you see this, cancel loading. Then head to inspect tab and look all the CSS properties it points to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of loading is called as skeleton loading effect. You have to follow some steps to achieve this effect

1. Create a skeleton for your items
2. Add transition and animation to the skeleton(placeholders).
3. Add `js` loading script and load multiple skeletons till loading finished.

You can follow this tutorial, if you need to clarify anything. [Skeleton tutorial](https://web-crunch.com/posts/how-to-create-skeleton-screen-loading-effect)